# using VF input fields to set request body for Rest API call

Tags: rest-api, post

I'm trying to send data from one SFDC org to another org via Rest API. 
I'm properly able to create Rest Resource in 'receiving org' in this way :

```
@httpPost
global static string DepositAmount(string Accountid, integer amount, date depositDate)
{  
 // ----My code doing processing
}
```

'Sending org' is sending data entered by user via VF page(using custom controller). As mentioned, user in inputting data in 3 fields of types :

```
1. Text
2. Number
3. Date
```

Now I'm able to make successful Rest API call if I send 'hardcoded' values to 'receiving org for above 3 fields in this way :

```
String strbody = '{  "AccountId" : "0019000001Gchjb", "depositAmount" : "4555", "depositDate" :"06/01/2014" }'
 req.setBody(strbody);
```

But I'm unsure How to set input Fields as request body for the API call ?
I was thinking to try JSON serialization using Maps

```
Map<String,String> postBody = new Map<String,String>();
```

But Maps accepts data of one type.  Here I've 3 types of Data . If I convert my data into string, my receiving org starts giving error as it accepts 3 values of different types( string, number, date)

How could I proceed to set body in receiving org ?

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't support all data types that are available in APEX. For an example there is no Date type in JSON. So I'd recommend you changing your method to accept 1 parameter of type String, which will be the JSON string itself. Then you can parse it and convert the JSON types to APEX accordingly. As you mentioned, I'd use a map and serialise/deserialise in order to pass the JSON string across:

**Sending org**

```
Id accountId = account.Id; // assume you have an instance of the account record
Decimal amount = 123.23; // input field value
Date depositDate = system.today(); // assumption agian

Map <String, String> jsonMap = new Map <String, String> ();
jsonmap.put('AccountId', account.Id); 
jsonmap.put('depositAmount', String.valueOf(amount));
jsonmap.put('depositDate', String.valueOf(depositDate));

String strbody = JSON.serialize(jsonMap);
req.setBody(strbody);
```

**Receiving org**

```
global static string DepositAmount(string jsonString)
{
    Map<String, Object> jsonRes = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
    Id accountId = (Id)jsonRes.get('AccountId');
    Decimal amount = Decimal.valueOf((String)jsonRes.get('depositAmount'));
    Date depositDate = Date.valueOf((String)jsonRes.get('depositDate'));
}
```

Comment: Oh! Failed to apply my thinking in that direction!  This seems like logical input.Thanks for that. Will try to apply it in my org and mark it as solution, if I don't come across any significant issue.

Comment: Hi Bachovski  -  I tried exactly what you've mentioned but in response in 'sending org', I'm getting this error :   RESPONSE_BODY[{"message":"Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: depositDate at [line:1, column:17]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}] .What it is not able to deserialize depostiDate? Am I missing something ?

Comment: Jump here - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25341/curious-techy